# Select section showing undefined in ajax autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I getting **name** perfectly but I am **not** getting their **name related ID** in **ajax autocomplete**

Following is the view code,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CustomerFullName, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.CustomerId)

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CustomerFullName").autocomplete({            
            source: function (request, response) {                
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Order")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (val) {                        
                        return {
                            value: val.Name,
                            label: val.Name
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert(ui.item.id);
                $("#CustomerId").val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the controller,

```
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string term = "")
{
    var objCustomerlist = (from customer in _customerRepository.Table
                           where customer.Username.StartsWith(term)
                           select new
                           {
                               Name = customer.Username,
                               ID = customer.Id
                           }).ToList();
    return Json(objCustomerlist);
}
```

**In autocomplete ajax select section alert showing undefined**

I tried things to solve like

1. JSON.Stringfy(ui.item.id)
2. ui.id

but still didnt work.